# How to calculate row number in MongoDB for sorted query?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, row-number

I have collection with photos and I have to show the current photo position in album. Sort conditions are complex: sort({added:1,weight:1,_id:1}) so there is no chance to check count of photos before current.

I tried to use MapReduce but it works very slow (615 ms) comparing with PostgreSQL (44ms).

What is the best practice to get row number of some element in Mongo?

Comment: As you know, MongoDB doesn't have row numbers, so what are you trying to do with a row number?

Comment: You want the Order of insert into your Photo collection ?

Comment: I just have to show current position of photo in album. For example: Current photo is 55 of 578. But I don't know the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pagination-like problem. Essentially, you should perform the counting client-side. If you want to have a stable order, you should sort by the `_id` field too (because it is immutable). Apparently, you're already doing that.

```
[pseudocode]
var criteria = { "album_id" : "foo", ... }; 
var skip = 50; // assuming we're on page 2 and each page has 50 photos 
var cursor = db.Photo.find(criteria).
       sort({"added" :1, "weight" : 1, "_id" : 1}).
       skip(skip).limit(50);
// count() doesn't honour skip or limit, so this is total number of 
// Photos matching 'criteria'
var count = cursor.count(); 

for(var i = 0; i < cursor.length; ++i)
    cursor[i].index = skip + i;
// each photo is now cursor[x].index of 'count' photos total
```

Hope that helps

Comment: But if user comes on page /photos/<id> I have to find position of current <id> to show: This is 10 of 50 photos. So I have every time to fetch full cursor and calculate position?

Comment: That sounds as if the index of the photo has a relevance of its own - can users modify their albums to change the position? In that case, it'd make sense to explicitly store this information, for example store the picture ids of each album in a list like `Album { Pictures:["id1", "id4", "id2", "id3"] }`. If not, you might want to modify the url scheme to `/albums/:albumId/images/:imageIndex`